# How to reorder columns header in SuperCsv Using CsvMapReader

Tags: csv, supercsv

I am using SuperCsv API , I am reading an existing csv and excluding few of the columns using csvMapReader; resultant map I am writing using csvMapWriter but the resulting csv is having column headers are not in natural order as that is in first csv. How to do it,

```
        Map<String, Object> csv_new_Map;
        while ((csv_new_Map = csvMapReader.read(headers, processors)) != null) {
            for (String exclude : exclusionDataSet) {
                csv_2G_Map.remove(exclude);
            }
         listOfRows.add(csvOrderedMap);
        }
         mapWriter.writeHeader(headers_x);

            for (int i = 0; i < listOfRows.size(); i++) {
                mapWriter.write(listOfRows.get(i), headers_x, processors_x);

            }
```

Any suggestions

Comment: Is this actually the code? Because it doesn't look you're using the `csv_new_Map` variable at all. Maybe you can post a complete example that demonstrates your problem? (e.g. a simple Junit test)